# Засада с вложенным циклом

Tags: python, pandas, for, pivot

Засел на простейшем вложенном цикле :(
У меня есть датасет из задания по Tripadvisor. Там есть рестораны, стили кухни, представленные в них, города и т.п.
Сделал `pivot_table`, в котором видно в каком городе представлено какое количество ресторанов по видам кухни

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df.explode('Cuisine Style'), values = ['ID_TA'], index = ['City'], columns = ['Cuisine Style'], aggfunc = 'count', fill_value = 0)
```

Теперь хочу пройтись по датасету вложенным циклом, чтобы для каждого ресторана вычислить сколько еще в городе представлено таких же кухонь, как в этом ресторане.
Написал такое:

```
for i in range(len(df['City'])):
city = df['City'].iloc[i]
rest_count_avg = []
for j in range(len(df['Cuisine Style'].iloc[i])):
    style = df['Cuisine Style'].iloc[i][j]
    n = table.loc[city]['ID_TA'][style]
    rest_count_avg.append(n)
res = np.mean(rest_count_avg)
df['test'].iloc[i]= res
```

Блокнот выдает ошибку

> (TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer).

Никак не могу понять ГДЕ я пытаюсь выдать строку за число в этом цикле???
Помогите, люди добрые :)

Comment: Во-первых приведите пример данных. Во-вторых - а какого типа у вас `city` и `style`? Скорее всего на попытки индексироваться по ним ругается.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать вот здесь:

```
n = table.loc[city]['ID_TA'][style]
```

Скорее всего ругается именно на эту строку, поскольку вы пытаетесь индексироваться через строковые переменные `city` и `style`. Возможно, вы хотели написать что-то типа:

```
n = table.loc[table.city == city, 'ID_TA']
```

Но вот дальше я вообще не понимаю, что вы хотели получить через `[style]`.

Приведите пример ваших данных (или кусок программы, который получает эти данные), чтобы можно было разбираться дальше.

Comment: n = table.loc[city]['ID_TA'][style] я тут пытаюсь выцепить значение из pivot_table

Comment: @AlexeiZhuravlev Попробуйте по шагам, не сразу всю конструкцию, а сначала первые скобки и посмотрите, что вернётся или какая ошибка, потом добавляете вторые скобки и т.д. Т.е. сначала пробуете `table.loc[city]` что вернёт (если вернёт)

Comment: @AlexeiZhuravlev, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)